# jQuery not working on elements created by jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am dynamically adding list items to a list in jQuery through an ajax call that is called every second.

Below is the code for the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/update_group_list.php',
    data: '', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var id = data.instructor_id;
            group_cnt = data.group_cnt,
            group_name = data.group_name,
            group_code = data.group_code;

            for (i = current_row; i < group_cnt; i++)
            {
                //setInterval(function() { $('#group-list-div').load('php/group_list.php'); }, 5000);

                $('#group-list').append("<li><a href='#' data-role='button' class='view-group-btns' id='"+group_code[i]+"' value='"+id+"' text='"+group_name[i]+"'>"+group_name[i]+"</a></li>");
                $('#delete-group-list').append("<fieldset data-role='controlgroup data-iconpos='right'>" +
                                                    "<input id='"+group_code[i]+i+"' value='"+group_code[i]+"' type='checkbox' name='groups[]'>" +
                                                    "<label for='"+group_code[i]+i+"'>"+group_name[i]+"</label>" +
                                                "</fieldset>");
            }

            current_row = i; 

            $('#group-list').listview('refresh');
            $('#delete-group-list').trigger('create');
    }
});
```

Now I am having two problems

FIRST PROBLEM:

When I try to run the code below (it should show an alert box if any of the list items created in this line $('#group-list').blah...blah in the code above), nothing happens.

```
$(".view-group-btns").click(function() 
{
    alert("check");
});
```

SECOND PROBLEM:

Also when I try to send the form data for the checkboxes (referencing line $('#delete-group-list').blah...blah in the ajax call code above) the post returns the error unexpected token <

What am I doing wrong? I think the two problems are related as I am creating the list items that are used dynamically.

---

Here is extra code relating to the SECOND problem

HTML:

```
<form id='delete-group-form' action='php/delete_groups.php' method='post'>
    <h3 style='text-align: center;'>Check the Box Beside the Groups you Would Like to Delete </h3>
    <div style='margin-top: 20px;'></div>
        <div id='delete-group-list'>
        </div>
    <div style='margin-top: 20px;'></div>
    <input type='submit' id='delete-groups-btn' data-theme='b' value='Delete Groups(s)'>                    
</form>
```

JS Code

```
$('#delete-group-form').submit(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();

    alert($('#delete-group-form').serialize());

    if ($('#delete-group-form').serialize() == "") 
    {
        alert('No groups selected to be deleted.')
        return false;
    }
    else 
        if ($('#delete-groups-form').serialize() == null) 
        {
            alert('No groups selected to be deleted.')
            return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $.post('php/delete_groups.php',$('#delete-groups-form').serialize()).done(function(data) 
            {
                obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);


                var group_codes = obj.group_list;

                alert(group_codes);

                alert("The selected groups have been deleted");
                window.setTimeout(2000);
                return false;
            });
        }
    return false;
});
```

delete_groups.php

```
<?php 
    $group_codes = $_POST['groups'];    
    $items = array('group_list'=>$group_codes); //creating an array of data to be sent back to js file
    echo json_encode($items); //sending data back through json encoding
?>
```

I think the root of the SECOND problem is the line $group_codes = $_POST['groups']; specfically the $_POST['groups'] because when I replace it with $group_codes = 'test'; (just for debugging purposes) , the code works as expected.

Comment: Don't use "a second problem", create a new question for that, please.

Comment: I put them in the same question because I think the root of the problem is the same. However, if you still feel I should make another question, I will make one.

Comment: The problems are not related. My guess is that this error is coming from update_group_list.php, show us the exact error.

Comment: update_group_list.php is fine I think because it doesnt show any error when I run that page specfically

Comment: Here is the exact error for the second problem ---- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
st.extend.parseJSON jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
(anonymous function) group_menu.js:137
f jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
p.fireWith jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
r jquery-1.9.0.min.js:3
r

Comment: For the first problem the error is that nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, you really should isolate your questions so people will bother to answer.

Comment: It tells you that the problem is in line 137 in group_menu.js. Show us that line.

Comment: Your JSON might be malformed. What does your PHP look like?

Comment: for your second problem you could set the header as `application/json` or just put an exit statement right after the `echo json_encode($items);`

Comment: @Jonast92 ,My bad I didnt see these new comments here. Line 137 is just "}" lol.

Comment: @so geek , could you tell me how to set a header or what the syntax is for the exit statement (im fairly new to php)

Comment: I created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116457/jquery-post-not-working-on-dynamic-jquery-elements

Comment: ok, put `exit();` after `echo json_encode($items);` or `header('Content-type: application/json');` at the top of your php file right after php tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use event delegation to make your newly-created elements function properly:

```
$("#group-list").on("click", ".view-group-btns", function() {
    alert("check");
});
```

Comment: Any ideas for the second problem? I pasted extra code for the second problem.

Comment: @aagarwal: Is that the *entire* PHP file?

Comment: Yes, that is the entire Php file. I will be adding more code later, relating to MySql, but I haven't gotten to that yet.

Comment: I think the problem is with the line $group_codes = $_POST['groups']; specfically the $_POST['groups'] because when I replace it with $group_codes = 'test'; , the code works as expected.

Comment: @aagarwal: Change the `dataType` to `'string'` and then `console.log()` the text out.

Comment: how do I change the dataType? and where should I use the console.log()?

Comment: To change dataType i just replace the ajax part with string?

Comment: @aagarwal: Yes. Add `console.log(data);` right before the `var id = ...` line

Comment: I did what you said and this is the output: {"instructor_id":"0","group_cnt":11,"group_name":["Science","Science 23","Test 4","Test 1","Lecture 5","Lecture 6","Lecture 7","Calculus 2","Calculus 3","Calculus 4","TEst 2 "],"group_code":["6625","7968","3145","6037","8533","4716","2474","8363","5629","6250","1019"]}

Comment: @aagarwal: Ask a separate question. I can't debug things well without actually seeing them.

Comment: I can create another question no problem but I just wanted to know what other things you would like to see. I have pasted all of the related code. If I was to create another question I would just move all of the SECOND PROBLEM parts from this question to the new question so there wouldn't be any extra code.

Comment: I created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116457/jquery-post-not-working-on-dynamic-jquery-elements

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you have 3 single quotes on this line... missed one after controlgroup

```
$('#delete-group-list')."<fieldset data-role='controlgroup data-iconpos='right'>"
```

That would explain the unexpected token <

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the jquery on event.

```
$(".view-group-btns").on("click", function(event)
{
    alert("check");
});
```

Why?

Because you can only use the regular "click" on elements that are created BEFORE the DOM is updated.

When you are dynamically creating new elements into the dom tree, then you can't use .click anymore.

on (and in the past, .live(), which is deprecated now) can listen to modifications in the DOM tree and can use the later-on created elements.

Comment: I had already updated that :) Thanks for the point though. But if it solved the problem then please upvote it and accept it.

Comment: `.on()` isn't a drop-in replacement for `.live()`. `.on('click'` is the same as `.click(`

Comment: Show us the exact error you mention in problem 2 (but really.. stackoverflow is about specific problems) and the code for the php file.

Comment: I know that It's not an replacement, and how can it be the same? It does the same behavior bit takes into account changed to the dom.

Comment: @Jonast92: Test it out if you'd like. You need to use the event delegation syntax of `.on()` to mimic `.live()`'s behavior.

Comment: I posted the exact error for problem 2 in the comments of the question but I will paste it here again. ----Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1 st.extend.parseJSON jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1 (anonymous function) group_menu.js:137 f jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1 p.fireWith jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1 r jquery-1.9.0.min.js:3 r

Comment: I only see the .view-group-btns once. That gives me the idea that the element already lives in the document. If you add the click again, like here, wouldn't it start stacking click event triggers?

Comment: @Daniel im not sure I understand what you are saying. .view-group-btns is used as a class and it is tagged into many list items. The line you saw it on is running as a while loop, hence it exists more than once.

Comment: @aagarwal - The remark relates to the answer given here. If another call is made to add an `on("click", ..` on an existing element, it will stack events. I recreated this in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/Na8pb/1/) Check the console and see it get fired multiple times when the event is added.

Comment: This might be a stupid question but w/e im fairly new to web development. By "stack events" you mean multiple alert boxes will open up?

Comment: Yes, but I use console.log to keep the script running and not stop on each alert. Change console.log with alert and adding events with the button will cause that you will need to click multiple times to get the alert box out the way.
Back on-topic I see that the class "view-group-btns" is generated in the ajax.success phase. Unless this class is unique, you could use the above solution in the same phase after creation after the for-loop and attach it to the group. Yet I am pretty sure that @Blender has the more elegant solution to this.

But I am breaking in on the other friends.

Comment: @Blender How is your answer different from mine? The coding approach is the same, you're just being more specific by adding the id first.

Comment: @Jonast92: `.on()` has two forms: the regular event handler binding syntax (`$('#elem').on('click', function() {...`) and the event delegation syntax (`$('#static-parent').on('click', '#elem', function() {...`). As I said before, try them out. Only the second form behaves like `.live()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the click function after you get the element from ajax call. Binding on pageLoad event will only bind with those elements that are already in the dom. So do something like this.

```
$.ajax({
success : function(res){
//bind your click function after you update your html dom.
}
})
```

Comment: Which problem is this for?

Comment: This is for your first problem