# JQuery post not working on dynamic jQuery elements

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

NOTE: This question is a split from the post: [jQuery not working on elements created by jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116173/jquery-not-working-on-elements-created-by-jquery)

I am dynamically adding list items to a list in jQuery through an ajax call that is called every second.

Below is the code for the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/update_group_list.php',
    data: '', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var id = data.instructor_id;
            group_cnt = data.group_cnt,
            group_name = data.group_name,
            group_code = data.group_code;

            for (i = current_row; i < group_cnt; i++)
            {
                //setInterval(function() { $('#group-list-div').load('php/group_list.php'); }, 5000);

                $('#group-list').append("<li><a href='#' data-role='button' class='view-group-btns' id='"+group_code[i]+"' value='"+id+"' text='"+group_name[i]+"'>"+group_name[i]+"</a></li>");
                $('#delete-group-list').append("<fieldset data-role='controlgroup data-iconpos='right'>" +
                                                    "<input id='"+group_code[i]+i+"' value='"+group_code[i]+"' type='checkbox' name='groups[]'>" +
                                                    "<label for='"+group_code[i]+i+"'>"+group_name[i]+"</label>" +
                                                "</fieldset>");
            }

            current_row = i; 

            $('#group-list').listview('refresh');
            $('#delete-group-list').trigger('create');
    }
});
```

when I try to send the form data for the checkboxes (referencing line $('#delete-group-list').blah...blah in the ajax call code above) the post returns the error unexpected token <

What am I doing wrong? I think the two problems are related as I am creating the list items that are used dynamically.

---

Here is extra code relating to the problem

HTML:

```
<form id='delete-group-form' action='php/delete_groups.php' method='post'>
    <h3 style='text-align: center;'>Check the Box Beside the Groups you Would Like to Delete </h3>
    <div style='margin-top: 20px;'></div>
        <div id='delete-group-list'>
        </div>
    <div style='margin-top: 20px;'></div>
    <input type='submit' id='delete-groups-btn' data-theme='b' value='Delete Groups(s)'>                    
</form>
```

JS Code

```
$('#delete-group-form').submit(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();

    alert($('#delete-group-form').serialize());

    if ($('#delete-group-form').serialize() == "") 
    {
        alert('No groups selected to be deleted.')
        return false;
    }
    else 
        if ($('#delete-groups-form').serialize() == null) 
        {
            alert('No groups selected to be deleted.')
            return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $.post('php/delete_groups.php',$('#delete-groups-form').serialize()).done(function(data) 
            {
                obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);


                var group_codes = obj.group_list;

                alert(group_codes);

                alert("The selected groups have been deleted");
                window.setTimeout(2000);
                return false;
            });
        }
    return false;
});
```

delete_groups.php

```
<?php 
    $group_codes = $_POST['groups'];    
    $items = array('group_list'=>$group_codes); //creating an array of data to be sent back to js file
    echo json_encode($items); //sending data back through json encoding
?>
```

I think the root of the SECOND problem is the line $group_codes = $_POST['groups']; specfically the $_POST['groups'] because when I replace it with $group_codes = 'test'; (just for debugging purposes) , the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, previously i thought the mistake with the content type header of php file, still its there (you need to specify the header type to parse with jQuery JSON). But found one more mistake which i suppose the cause of the problem.

```
<form id='delete-group-form' action='php/delete_groups.php' method='post'>
```

and the form you wish to serialize is

```
$('#delete-groups-form').serialize()
```

You can see the difference in IDs. This will return an empty object, where in php file it expects the index called `groups` which never exists. Therefore it'll return an undefined index error as an html content type which starts with `<html>`, with that JSON parser return an error with `unexpected token <`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$_POST['groups'];` (in your delete_groups.php) it looks for the content sent from the form element with an attribute `name="groups"`, but your delete-group-form doesn't have any such element.

The "`error unexpected token <`" message may be from a separate issue.  Validating your HTML might reveal the issue.

Also, I'm not entirely clear on why you're using two separate functions (the $.post in your JS and the $.ajax).  Unless there's something else going on that I can't see from the code you've posted, you could simplify it considerably by just using one call to ajax.  Put that one call inside the `$('#delete-group-form').submit(function(e)` in place of the `$.post`, and pass your `groups` variable using the `ajax` call's data parameter.  Modify delete_groups.php to return the necessary information (currently returned from update_group_list.php) to update the display on your page.